# Spring transaction: unexpected rollback behavior

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions, jdbctemplate

I am doing a simple experiment for debugging purpose.

First I insert serveral records to database, and then I do a invalid data conversion which will throw DataIntegrityViolationException, but I will catch the exception.

I expected the records being successfully inserted into the db, since I catch the checked exception. But the whole thing is rolled back.

I do the experiment again using TransactionTemplate instead of using annotation, same result.

My questions are:

1. is this the expected behavior?
2. If anwser to No.1 is yes, then I catch the exception, how is it possible that spring knows an exception is thrown?

Here is my code:

```
public void insertValue() {
    jdbcTemplate.execute("insert into people (person_id, name) values (4, 'asjkdhadsjkqhweqkewhkashdkahd')");
    jdbcTemplate.execute("insert into people (person_id, name) values (5, 'tttqqq')");
}
// this should throw exception
public void truncateValue() {
    jdbcTemplate.execute("alter table people alter column name varchar(7)");
}

public void jdbc_calls() {
    insertValue();
    try {
        truncateValue();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("Finish");
}

public void run() {
    TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);

    transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED);
    transactionTemplate.setIsolationLevel(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_DEFAULT);

    transactionTemplate.execute(transactionStatus -> {
        try {
            jdbc_calls();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return null;
    });
}
```

More about question No.2. 
Here is the source code of TransactionTemplate.execute()
From my understanding, if I don't throw an exception, rollbackOnException won'r be triggered.

```
public <T> T execute(TransactionCallback<T> action) throws TransactionException {
    Assert.state(this.transactionManager != null, "No PlatformTransactionManager set");

    if (this.transactionManager instanceof CallbackPreferringPlatformTransactionManager) {
        return ((CallbackPreferringPlatformTransactionManager) this.transactionManager).execute(this, action);
    }
    else {
        TransactionStatus status = this.transactionManager.getTransaction(this);
        T result;
        try {
            result = action.doInTransaction(status);
        }
        catch (RuntimeException | Error ex) {
            // Transactional code threw application exception -> rollback
            rollbackOnException(status, ex);
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Transactional code threw unexpected exception -> rollback
            rollbackOnException(status, ex);
            throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(ex, "TransactionCallback threw undeclared checked exception");
        }
        this.transactionManager.commit(status);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. is this the expected behavior?

Yes, it is.

> 2. If anwser to No.1 is yes, then I catch the exception, how is it possible that spring knows an exception is thrown?

When an exception occurs, spring will mark your transaction as `rollbackOnly`. 
So even when you catch your exception, at the end of your method, your transaction still rolled back.

In your case, I don't get why you use `@Transaction` since you want to commit regardless if exception occurs.

**Edit**

When you're using transaction with DB, the transaction invocation is delegated to EntityManager.

Look at `AbstractEntityManagerImpl#handlePersistenceException`:

```
@Override
public void handlePersistenceException(PersistenceException e) {
    if ( e instanceof NoResultException ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( e instanceof NonUniqueResultException ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( e instanceof LockTimeoutException ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( e instanceof QueryTimeoutException ) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        markForRollbackOnly();
    }
    catch ( Exception ne ) {
        //we do not want the subsequent exception to swallow the original one
        LOG.unableToMarkForRollbackOnPersistenceException(ne);
    }
}
```

When exception occurs, the EntityManager mark your transaction as `rollbackOnly` before throws out the exception for you to catch.

After the exception is catched in your service, the `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager` will try to commit (because, as you know, no exception is detected there), but the EntityManager refuses to commit because its detect that the transaction marked as rollback-only.

If you read the exception, you will see something like:

> javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly

Comment: Thank you! do you know where "spring will mark your transaction as rollbackOnly"? I am reading the source code of TransactionTemplate but couldn't find it.... btw, this example is made up only for debugging purpose

Comment: I trying to put a break point in AbstractEntityManagerImpl, but this class is not used.   TransactionTemplate.execute() is being called

Comment: So you're using different transaction manager. The idea is same. The class for your usecase is different. I will comeback to you tômrow with the class for your usecase, now I have to sleep ^^

Comment: Hey you already change `@Transaction` to `TransactionTemplate`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173149/discussion-between-user2628641-and-mnh-quyt-nguyn).

Comment: @Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn, I want to ignore exceptions due to duplicate key while inserting. Kindly suggest if there is way in Declarative or programmatic spring transaction. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343137/problem-in-handling-unit-of-work-using-hibernate-jpa